# Logging into Facebook App redirects to canvas URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

So I've started learning facebook application and got my first obstacle. Whenever i log into my simple hello user application, i'm redirected into canvas URL (App content opens on server directly, instead inside facebook iFrame).

Here's the code

```
<?php
require_once("php-sdk/facebook.php");

$config = array(
    'appId' => '',
    'secret' => ''
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$params = array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/401822713222945/'
);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>

    <body>
<?php
if ($user_id){
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo 'Welcome ' . $user_profile['name'] . '!';
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '" onclick="top.location.href = \'' . $login_url . '\'">log in.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '" onclick="top.location.href = \'' . $login_url . '\'">log in.</a>';
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the settings for your application are correct? I edited out your App ID and secret, if I were your I'd generate a new secret.

Comment: Thanks for edit! Well i suppose so but i better check twice then.

Comment: It's not the case that you have "Website with Facebook Login" and "App on Facebook"?

Comment: I've set the app as App on Facebook only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following right after the `<body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top === self){
    document.location = "<?php echo $params['redirect_uri'];?>";
}
</script>
```

It will check if the current window is the most top window, if you're accessing the page directly it will then redirect you to the iframed page.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it does work, altho i'm still concered why this thing happens, i was doing the App at same time with my friend, and our code was pretty much the same, but the redirection was broken at mine's only.

Comment: Hello Karl, I have same redirect problem, i have use above code in my app, and problem is solved, but when new user open application then no authentication dialog is open. :(. because of you provide a static url for redirect.. Can you help me??

Comment: @Rajnish Have you debugged the redirect_uri, what does it look like?

Comment: yes, i have debug, But it is a facebook app url with state and token as usual,

Comment: If that's the redirect_uri then this does not seem to be related to this question. If you like, please create a new question where you explain everything and feel free to ping me when you've done that.